# Ways to solve a 2D Laplace equation

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I'm looking for a survey of methods to solve Laplace equation in two dimensions.

Is there a book describing them with hints regarding their applicability for various cases?

I mean analytical methods, not numerics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Community bumped the question, I might as well put something relevant here. My reaction to seeing "two dimensions" and "Laplace equation" in the same sentence is "ooh, I can use conformal maps to do that". The idea is that since the Laplace equation is invariant under conformal maps, we can transform our boundary value problem into a BVP on a nicer domain, a disk or a halfplane. This works very well for the Dirichlet problem; for the Neumann problem the boundary conditions must be multiplied by the derivative of the conformal map, which makes life a bit harder.

- [Low-level explanation with lots of examples and pictures](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/DirichletProblemMod.html). Unfortunately it dates  back to 2003 when MathJax wasn't around. We are spoiled by MathJax now.
- [Conformal Mapping: Methods and Applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=Aw4SOBFKF2kC), Dover book by Roland Schinzinger and Patricio A. A. Laura. From the preview it looks very thorough and accessible.
- [Research-level explanation with emphasis on polygonal domains](http://www.math.udel.edu/~driscoll/talks/oxford03.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

Here, I am giving you a link. See the file. You will get some hint.
http://newton.ex.ac.uk/teaching/CDHW/EM/CW970317-2.pdf

Books:

1. Schaum's Series - Laplace Transformation
2. Laplace Transforms for Electronic Engineers by JAMES G. HOLBROOK

Comment: Books on Laplace Transforms will likely not give too much information on solving the Laplace equation.